# GROUP BY a, b VS GROUP BY b, a

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I was wondering if there is any difference between order of grouping in `GROUP BY a, b` and `GROUP BY b, a` (I know the final result is the same). If so, would it affect the query's speed?

Comment: no  difference .... anyway check the related  explain plan

Comment: not in theory (but I wouldn't guarantee the same performance in some engines with unfinished optimization of the implementation - when `a` and `b` are some computed values from a window function inside a correlated subquery or something...)

Answer (score 4):

A `group by` clause just defines the unique combination of field(s) which would be considered a group. There is no meaning to the order these fields are stated.

Comment: This is actually not correct. See the example above.

Answer (score 3):

It does matter if you have multiple-column indexes. You should define the `GROUP BY` columns in the order of the index.

So, if you have an index for (a,b) then you should use `GROUP BY a, b` and MySQL is able to take full advantage of the index.

See [example](https://mydbr.com/demo/mydbr/report.php?r=286&m=4&h=9aa48bbdfdefc4259152ac3e5f8ccf19c438ddb6)